# How to connect to Netezza (PureData System for Analytics) via VBA

Tags: sql, vba, excel, odbc, netezza

I am trying to connect to connect to Netezza using VBA. I have enabled the following:

- Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library
- Microsoft Office 15.0 Object Library
- Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library
- Visual Basic for Applications

Here is my code:

```
Sub NZConn()

Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim x As Variant

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Set RS = New ADODB.Recordset

cmd.ActiveConnection = "Driver={Netezza " & _
"ODBC};servername=servername;port=####;database=database;" & _
"username=username;password=password;"

cmd.ActiveConnection.CursorLocation = adUseClient
cmd.CommandTimeout = 120
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

x = "Write Query here"
cmd.CommandText = x

Set rs = cmd.Execute
Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs

cmd.ActiveConnection.Close

End Sub
```

I can get the code to run without throwing back an error, but there is nothing that is pasted from the record set, which leads me to believe that is may have something to do with the structure of the connection string.

I have the server, user id, password, database, port, and driver.

Would I need to establish / open an ActiveConnection first?

Comment: try `servername=servername,portnumber`

Comment: Subtract `New` from declaration as `Dim cmd As ADODB.Command` and `Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset`. And make sure rs is lowercase as `Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset`.

Comment: Driver={NetezzaSQL};servername=myServerAddress;port=myPortNumber;
database=myDataBase;username=myUsername;password=myPassword

Comment: The above comment seems to be the proper connection string for Netezza ODBC, so I am led to believe that it is something about how I am defining the dimensions. When I run this code now, I am getting an error that states : "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure out the issue on my own. I found that there is a command line builder in the 'Tools' tab in Aginity, which helped specify the exact connection string I needed to connect to Netezza. Once I had this connection string, I was getting an 'architecture mismatch' error. After downloading the 32-bit ODBC drivers for Netezza, the methodology worked perfectly. Here is the updated code below:

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset        
Dim iCols As Integer             
Dim DB As String, User As String, PW As String, ConnectionString As String
Dim Server As String, Query As String
Dim SQLTable As Worksheet

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set SQLTable = Sheet1

Server = SQLTable.Cells(2,3).Value
User = SQLTable.Cells(2,4).Value
PW = SQLTable.Cells(2,5).Value
DB = SQLTable.Cells(2,6).Value
Query = SQLTable.Cells(2,7).Value

ConnectionString = "Driver={NetezzaSQL};" & _
                   "server=" & Server & ";" & _
                   "UserName=" & User & ";" & _
                   "Password=" & PW & ";" & _
                   "Database=" & DB & ";" & _
                   "Query Timeout=120"

cn.Open (ConnectionString)
rs.Open (Query), cn

For iCols = 0 To RS.Fields.count - 1
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, iCols + 1).Value = rs.Fields(iCols).Name
Next
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, "A").CopyFromRecordset rs

rs.Close
cn.Close
```

NB:

- "IBM NETEZZA ODBC DRIVER – 32 BIT" is what I downloaded
- "ODBC-DRIVER-FOR-NETEZZA-7-X86" is what showed up in my software center to install
- "Name: NetezzaSQL ; Version: 7.00.04.41188 ; Company: www.ibm.com ; File: NSQLODBC.DLL" is what is shown now in my 32-bit 'ODBC Data Source Administrator' window

Answer (score 1):

I think your connection string is ok, and yes you should need to open a connection first.

Like this:

```
AccessConnect = "Driver={Netezza " & _
"ODBC};servername=servername;port=####;database=database;" & _
"username=username;password=password;"

Dim Conn1 As New adodb.Connection
Conn1.ConnectionString = AccessConnect
Conn1.Open
```

then it would be

```
Set RS = Conn1.Execute(x) 'where x is your query
```

Comment: I have been continuing on this issue and have yet to find a working product like I have for Oracle and Microsoft SQL Server.